# Delete columns of table where the sum of column adds to zero

Tags: list-manipulation

Given,

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 
    0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};
```

Delete the columns whose sum totals to zero. Specifically, columns 2 and 4. I have tried creating a list of the sums:

```
list = Total[data, {1}];
{15, 0, 15, 0, 15}
```

and then summing through this list and deleting the cases in "data" where its total is zero. However, this is not working. If anyone could help me with this problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: ``Transpose@Pick[Transpose@data, Map[Positive, list]]``

Comment: Yoou could do `Transpose[Select[Transpose[data], Total@# != 0 &]]` (Edit: Domen beat me to it by 4 seconds!)

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Comment: ```Transpose@data /. x_ /; Total[x] == 0 -> Nothing // Transpose```

Comment: ``Map[Cases[#, x_ /; x > 0] &, data]``

Comment: ``Pick[data, Map[Positive, data]]``

Answer (score 5):

```
f1 = Transpose @* Select[UnequalTo[0] @* Tr] @* Transpose;

f1 @ data
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}
> ```

```
f2 = Transpose @* DeleteCases[_?(EqualTo[0] @* Tr)] @* Transpose;

f2 @ data
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}
> ```

Comment: particularly like f1 +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

And another fun one

```
Drop[data, 
  None, {##, 2} & @@ Flatten@Position[Total@data, 0]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: res]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `SequenceCases`:

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};
```

[image]

```
Transpose[Map[If[SequenceCases[#, list_ /; Total[list] =!= 0] === {}, Nothing, #] &, Transpose[data]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is the following:

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};
```

[image]

```
Transpose[Map[If[Total[data[[All, #]]] === 0, Nothing, data[[All, #]]] &, Range[Length[data]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `Table`:

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};
```

[image]

```
Transpose[Table[If[Total[data[[All, i]]] > 0, data[[All, i]], Nothing], {i, 1, Length[data]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 
    0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};

pos = Flatten@Position[Total[data], 0]
```

> {2, 4}

```
data[[All, pos]] = Nothing
```

Result:

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}

Comment: Hi @Syed! Welcome to the party called by @Nasser :)

Answer (score 2):

We have

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 
    0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};

data // MatrixForm
```

> [image: mat1]

1. Use [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) and [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) to locate which columns you want removed and then [`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) to delete them.

The code is:

```
Transpose@
  Delete[Transpose@data, Position[Total@data, 0]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: mat2]

2. This is a minor comment. You can use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) as was suggested in the comment but there's no need for [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

The code is:

```
Select[Total@# != 0 &] /@ data // MatrixForm
```

> [image: mat2]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, another possibility is to use `MapIndexed` (there has to be at least 10 different ways to solve the same problem in Mathematica. I counted only 7 so far (including in comments). This forum needs to become more active :)

```
data = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3, 0, 3}, {4, 0, 4, 0, 4}, {5, 0, 5, 0, 5}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sum = Total[data, {1}]
MapIndexed[If[#1 == 0, data[[All, First[#2]]] = Sequence[], Nothing] &, sum];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Most of the times, I keep forgetting about our friend the `MapIndexed`. Not sure why. Nicely done!!!

Comment: @bmf  the `mapindexed` is like the `enumerate` in python :). which will give you the element and index at the same time.

Comment: @AsukaMinato not a python user, but thanks for letting me know. At some point I have to teach myself :) I am aware what `MapIndexed` does, but for some reason it will slip my mind most of the times...my dysfunctional brain :)

Answer (score 2):

Since @Nasser wrote the infamous statement about the 10 ways, I cannot resist.

```
Drop[data, None, 
  Append[2]@Flatten@Position[Total@data, 0]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: res]